# Finding builds in Team Explorer's "My Builds"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-in, tfsbuild

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2012 add-in which extends Build Explorer - basically, I add a context menu option for every build (completed or running, but not queued). Following [a blog post about doing this in VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/04/08/tfs-2010-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-completed-builds-context-menu-in-the-build-explorer.aspx), I managed to do so for builds that appear in Builder Explorer - hooray!

Now, my context menu also appear in Team Explorer's `Builds` pages, `My Builds` section. However, when I get the callback, I can't find the actual builds anywhere!

Here's my beforeQueryStatus event handler, where I try to find out whether I have a build to show or not:

```
private void OpenCompletedInBuildExplorerBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cmd = (OleMenuCommand)sender;
    var vsTfBuild = (IVsTeamFoundationBuild)GetService(typeof(IVsTeamFoundationBuild));

    // This finds builds in Build Explorer window
    cmd.Enabled = (vsTfBuild.BuildExplorer.CompletedView.SelectedBuilds.Length == 1
                && vsTfBuild.BuildExplorer.QueuedView.SelectedBuilds.Length == 0); // No build _requests_ are selected

    // This tries to find builds in Team Explorer's Builds page, My Builds section
    var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
    var page = teamExplorer.CurrentPage as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase;  
    var vm = page.ViewModel;
    // does not compile: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageViewModel' is inaccessible due to its protection level
    var vm_private = vm as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageViewModel;
    // But debugger shows that if it did, my builds would be here:
    var builds = vm_private.MyBuilds;
}
```

1. Is there a way to get the list of builds?
2. More generally, is there a way to get some "window which this context menu belong to"? Currently I'm just looking around in parts of VS I assume would have builds...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the build using reflection:

```
var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));

var BuildsPage = teamExplorer.CurrentPage as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase;
var PageViewModel = BuildsPage.ViewModel as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageViewModelBase;
    // PageViewModel is actually Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildsPageViewModel. But, it's private, so get SelectedBuilds through reflection
var SelectedBuilds = PageViewModel.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedBuilds").GetValue(PageViewModel) as System.Collections.IList;
if (SelectedBuilds.Count != 1)
{
    cmd.Enabled = false;
    return;
}

object BuildModel = SelectedBuilds[0];
    // BuildModel is actually Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.BuildModel. But, it's private, so get UriToOpen through reflection
var BuildUri = BuildModel.GetType().GetProperty("UriToOpen").GetValue(BuildModel) as Uri;
// TODO: Use BuildUri...

cmd.Enabled = true;
```